# Open Circuit in DC Voltage Source

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, dc

In this circuit with the switch closed:
[image]

It's a classic DC circuit with various currents flowing through and voltage drops across the resistors. My question is if we open the switch:

[image]

Does the voltage source have any effect on the circuit? The other connection of the DC source isn't connected to anything, and isn't connected to ground, would that circuit be meaningless? Or would the DC source just have no effect on the rest of the circuit anymore?

Comment: Do you mean if the voltage source have any effect on the circuit when the switch is open? Apart from current stop flowing, all nodes except for V- would float to V+ with respect to ground elsewhere (not shown in the schematic). Is this what you are asking?

Comment: @winny Ground elsewhere? I don't see how you can reference this circuit to a ground 'elsewhere'.

Comment: @GodJihyo It takes a bit of imagination. Hold a battery in mid air and connect something to one of its poles. That "circuit" will have super high impedance to earth but non the less that entire circuit is at the same potential.

Comment: @winny So then it would depend on the ratio of the impedances from the positive and negative sides of the source to 'ground', no? If they're equal the positive side would be at 1/2 Vsource wrtg and, the negative side at -1/2 Vsource wrtg, I suppose the resistors would be at V+ if V- is shorted to ground, 0V if V+ is shorted to ground, and somewhere in between for any other impedances. Now my brain hurts. :D

Comment: @GodJihyo Yes, but if you have some 100 Gohm to ground, the 10’s of kohm in OPs circuit won’t matter, they will all be effectively at V+ potential.

Comment: @winny I'm saying why does the + side get 100 Gohm and the - side get 0 ohm? In your battery example, if you have a wire  with 100 Gohm to ground, it's at ground potential. If you hook it to a battery + terminal it's still at ground potential unless there's a path for current through the battery - terminal. If that path is another 100 Gohm, then you get a voltage on the wire with respect to ground, but it's only half the battery voltage as each 100 Gohm will drop half the voltage. It's a voltage divider with the center grounded.

Comment: @GodJihyo No, battery is floating. 100 Gohm from each pole of the battery to ground. If OP opens the switch in the diagram, the V- node will be pushed to V volt below V+ and the rest of the circuit will be very close to V+ potential.

Answer (score 0):

The current path is broken, therefore, no, the voltage source has no impact. In practice, a switch and source are not perfectly isolated so you could see some leakage.

Answer (score 0):

In your ideal example, no.  Once the switch is opened, there is no effect besides everything floating at the same potential.  *However*, in real or more complex circuits, there are a few issues to consider.

As @winny mentioned, the resultant voltage at which all the nodes (except the one on the - end of the voltage source) reach will be at a higher voltage than ground, unless for some reason you've specified ground to be the + end of the voltage source.  In your example, a ground node isn't specified but the circuit is trivial so it doesn't take much analysis to see that there are no other current paths.

In more complex circuits, low side switching - breaking the ground connection to a component while leaving the positive supply attached - can have unintended effects, current leakage through I/O pins of ICs and things like that.  In other circuits, especially power supplies, circuit ground is connected to earth/chassis ground.  This can cause issues when e.g. connecting different modules or systems together.

Answer (score 0):

The analysis you're doing is the basic idealized nodal circuit analysis. In such analyses, there are no switches. You either have something connected or not. Any two-terminal source with one terminal open is considered to be "out of circuit" - it is deleted from the circuit before analysis starts.

So, with the switch in the circuit, you can't analyze it. You either have to remove the switch (when it's closed), or remove both the switch and the source it "gates" (when it's open).

You can of course, if you really want, replace the switch with either a 0Ω resistor when the switch is closed, or a 0S (zero Siemens) conductance (=infinity Ω). This just grows the size of the matrix representation of the circuit, since there's one more node than there otherwise would be. So there's little benefit to that.